# Definition: cofinal functor between triangulated categories

Tags: category-theory, definition, triangulated-categories

In Def 1.1 [this paper](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masiap/research/frob5.pdf) it says about a functor between triangulated categories $i:C \rightarrow D$ is *cofinal*.

This does not seem to be the usual one for categories. Am I correct in understanding that it means

> $i$ is cofinal iff For all $d \in D$ exists some $c$, such that $d$ is a direct some of $i(c)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the definition says, $i$ must be fully faithful and every object of $D$ must be a summand of an object in the image of $i$. You are right that this is essentially unrelated to the generally category theory notion of cofinality.